# Powershell Script - MSI package could not be opened

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, windows-server-2012, amazon-ami, packer

I created an Powershell Script to execute an MSI Installer from Packer AMI Build has ended up following error,

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\managesoft\FlexNetInventoryAgent.msi

> This installation package could not be opened.  Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

Below is my PowerShell script,

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://jfrog/artifactory/generic-flexera-flexera-one-virtual/PROD/Windows%20-%20Silent%20Install/managesoft.zip -OutFile "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\managesoft.zip" -Headers @{ "X-JFrog-Art-Api" = "$artifactory_key"} 
Expand-Archive -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\managesoft.zip -DestinationPath C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\managesoft
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\managesoft" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".msi"} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' ','' }
$msi_install_path = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\managesoft" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".msi"} | % {Write-Host $_.FullName}
msiexec.exe /i "$msi_install_path" /qn
```

Comment: still the same,
"This installation package could not be opened.  Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

Comment: `msiexec.exe` is telling you that the path you specified for the MSI file is not correct. Fix that and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$msi_install_path value is null in your case as full path of msi is being written to host but not being assigned to variable. Following should work:

```
$msi_install_path = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\managesoft" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".msi"} | % { $_.FullName }
```